# How much retagging is too much?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a number of posts (let's say 30+) that I believe could benefit from an added tag.  Is there a volume at which retagging becomes an annoyance to other users?

The posts in question have a specific tag but lack a more general one.  I believe the posts are more likely to be viewed if they have the new tag.

**edited to add**
I'd like to add the Salesforce tag to questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671252/visualforce-if-statement-need-to-know-syntax-for-or) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110868/add-custom-apexinputfile-icon-image). If it has the Visualforce tag, it is certainly a Salesforce question.  With the Salesforce tag, it should be easier to find.  I hope to bring more attention to the Salesforce questions here which seem to get less attention than those at Salesforce StackExchange.

Comment: What is the specific tag, what is the more general tag, and what is an example of a question that you believe requires the additional tag?

Comment: I've re-tagged about 10 or so.  I've kept it to posts that had, at least to me, some merit.

Answer (score 12):

Please do comprehensive edits. As long as your suggested edits are not "too minor" (aka too little done and too much left undone), feel free to improve any post you come across, including adding tags where you feel it is appropriate.

Improving the site is the reason you may edit posts.

Comment: Perhaps some of the confusion comes from wondering whether "too little done **and** too much left undone" implies that high-quality posts with only one specific problem are okay for sub-2k users to edit.

Comment: Emphasis on **too little done and too much left undone**.  Adding an appropriate tag is great, but don't leave other problems unresolved.

Comment: @AirThomas: They can be, though it depends on the one single problem encountered which will be fixed. A single typo? Probably not, though you can depend on the robots to accept that, even the other way around ;-)