# How much retagging should one user undertake without community input?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits

After reading the recently posted meta post about a specific [mass retagging instance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288749/tag-editor-extraordinaire), I wanted to circle back and address a broader question that didn't really seem like it was covered in the discussion of that specific case. While the answers there seem to focus on the quality and validity of the edits themselves, I'm interested in the community's opinion of whether it's appropriate, broadly speaking, for a single user to decide to retag 395 (or any arbitrarily large number of) posts in one sitting without turning to other members of the community for input. To my eye, this seems like a rather drastic action to take unilaterally even if the quality of the edits is high, but I'm interested to hear what others think.

I searched to see if there was any historical discussion of this and did find a prior question asking [how much retagging is too much](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261588/how-much-retagging-is-too-much), but the only answer that was provided there seems to just address best practices for good retag edits, without really getting to the question if there's such a thing as too many edits regardless of their quality.

Per the discussion that's happened here, the idea that makes the most sense to me would be for there to be an automatic moderator flag raised if a single user either adds or removes the same tag from more than X number (10? 20?) of posts in a certain timeframe (30 minutes? an hour?), while making no (or minimal) change to the post itself. I'm retagging this with [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request); I'd love to hear people's opinions on that idea, and especially the feelings of any moderators as to whether that's something they'd be interested in having in place.

Comment: If so, are you asking for a rate limit on edits to be put in place?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, hence this being a discussion post rather than a feature request. My gut says yes, there ought to be some limit, but I'm not sure whether that would make sense as a per day limit, or frequency limit, or something else. Maybe not though, because I don't have a fundamental problem with just the number of edits, but more the lack of any sort of consensus gathering for them. A handful of edits is just cleanup, but 395 of the same edits feels more like enforcing a perceived policy, which warrants discussion.

Comment: Theoretically, whenever anyone wants to retag that many posts, they should be following the process for tag removal: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work/250934#250934

Comment: @BradLarson I keep reading here that *everything* on SO is rate-limited. If this is an exception, it shouldn't be.

Comment: @EPJ It probably is rate limited to prevent attacks or bots, but not so much as to prevent an actual user going through and manually using the site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The number of edits is mostly irrelevant. The deciding factor is the *reason* for the edits.

Any retagging you do without a Meta post should primarily be **based on the relation of the question with the tags** and not on your opinion of the usefulness, appropriateness, clarity, etc. of the tags. (Exceptions include when a tag is widely known to be bad and usage is explicitly recommended against; this is sometimes recorded in the tag wiki itself.) Tag cleanup should almost never be done unilaterally.

Here's why:

1. You don't know everything about the subject matter. Seek knowledge from other users. This will result in improved ideas or confirmation that your ideas are widely agreed with.
2. You don't know everything about Stack Overflow. How do you know a retag effort related to yours is not in progress? An existing retag effort might even be contradictory to yours! [That has happened before.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283060/1394393)

This question does suggest, however, that maybe number of edits could be used as a heuristic for detecting this sort of unilateral behavior. If you want some kind of automated limiting or warning, then the algorithm should only consider edits that are tag only (or maybe tag only plus a small [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or simlar). Or potentially it could look for the same tag change repeatedly (disregarding whether other edits occurred).

But there's a major problem with this: how do you distinguish unilateral efforts from legitimate, Meta-approved efforts? Or alternatively, how do you set up a system so that the warnings or limitations work even for legitimate efforts?

Comment: Your last thought is something that I'd considered - maybe someone adding or removing the same tag more than XX times in a row should trigger a moderator alert?

Comment: @sphanley The big problem with that is that it would trigger far more useless flags from legitimate retagging efforts than it would useful flags of unilateral behavior. I've edited this answer to reflect that reality. (In the process, your reference to "last thought" should now be "next to last thought".) Feel free to unaccept if you feel the meaning has changed too much.