# Undefine [define]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I've come across the [[define] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/define/info), which appears to have basically no meaning. It's used by users both [in the context of C's `#define`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229765/how-can-we-pass-whole-array-in-define-as-argument), but also for ['How can I define X in language'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085969/defining-and-calling-upon-your-own-function-in-matlab).

The tag has no wiki and has been used over a thousand times.

Comment: Suggested title for this question: undefine [define]

Comment: One should not confuse "dank meme, bro" with "this is a better title".

Comment: What would be the appropriate use for [php's define](http://www.php.net/define)?

Comment: @ArtjomB. how about [constants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/constants) + the PHP tag

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The majority of these are actually [c-preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-preprocessor) questions, but there's unfortunately enough scattered use for other reasons that a manual cleanup is in order.

I've blocked it to stop more from coming in, users trying to apply it will see this message:

> Please don't use 'define' as a tag, it is deprecated and will soon be removed. If you're talking about the C preprocessor, use c-preprocessor instead. If you're using it for another reason, please just ensure that you've applied the appropriate language and / or applicable framework tags, and described your problem in detail.

This will also (annoyingly, perhaps) block edits that don't remove the tag, where the simplest fix is .. *to remove the tag*.

The wide-spectrum use of it kind of prohibits making it a synonym, so yeah, it has to go. Fortunately, the tide is held back while it's being cleaned up :)

Answer (score 14):

Its usage seems vague at best, including giving preference to `C` macros.

For example: `How do I define x given context y?`. Substitute whatever value you wish for `x` and `y`, neither `x` or `y` benefits from a tag called `define`.

It can probably just be done away with without incident **...But** questions that are specifically about `C` macros that don't have a  [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) tag but do include [define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/define) should replace `define` for `macros`. I think the [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) tag covers this case.

> A macro is a rule or pattern that specifies how a certain input sequence (often a sequence of characters) should be mapped to an output sequence (also often a sequence of characters) according to a defined procedure. The mapping process that instantiates (transforms) a macro into a specific output sequence is known as macro expansion.

However [community consensus should be reached](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288772/2126755) before making mass tag edits.

Comment: [c-preprocessor] is a more specific option for retagging.

Comment: I'd say that the most sensible option would be to follow the example of the (potentially ambiguous) [`switch`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/switch/info) tag and use `define-statement` for the C preprocessor macro.

Comment: @GoBusto: I agree in principle, but `#define` (unlike `switch`) is not a statement...

Comment: @psmears [`define-directive`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Directive_%28programming%29&oldid=628680833#The_C_preprocessor), then?