# Adding Python tag to non version-specific Python questions -- is it acceptable?

Tags: discussion, tags

Something I've noticed in my short time here is that new users often ignore the recommendation in the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) and [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) tags to

> Use the more generic [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag if your question is not version-specific.

Let me clarify that I'm talking about questions that are **unquestionably** non-version specific (*pretty easy to tell in Python*). Resultantly, they'll generate very little views on their respective questions even if they're the sort of questions the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) following folks like to jump all over and provide 8 solutions to in 15 minutes, since for instance [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) has ~15 times less followers than [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) .

This is great news for those people like me that are following the version-specific tags in addition to the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag as it gives me a ***much*** better chance of answering a question first, however it hardly guarantees the OP the same quality of answers or at least level of views as they would get with the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag.

You could maybe argue these people deserve less views for neglecting to read the tag descriptions, but could suggesting an edit (*out of the OP's best interest*) to add the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag to non version-specific questions when I happen to see them be an acceptable action? I witnessed a bit of a kerfuffle here yesterday regarding the [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tag which made me question this enough to ask about it here.

Comment: A big part of that "kerfuffle" was that the user in question [single-handedly edited hundreds of questions in a single sitting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288772/176646). If you're just re-tagging questions as they pop up, it's not a big a deal. That user was also doing the exact opposite of what you're proposing here: they were *removing* a more generic tag that still applied perfectly well (or so say the other users in that Meta post, I'm not familiar with VBA), as opposed to *adding* a more generic tag.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I appreciate the insight, they are very much not the same, thanks :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ...could suggesting an edit (*out of the OP's best interest*) to add the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag to non version-specific questions when I happen to see them be an acceptable action?

Yes!

In general, if there's a more appropriate tag that could replace or add to existing tags, that's a perfectly reasonable edit suggestion. That being said, do try to fix anything else you can while you're editing it.

Comment: Of course yeah, I like associating edits with myself that (*hopefully*) fix everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, adding the tag helps everybody:

- OP because not everyone has the specific python+version tags in their filters (not that it's difficult, mind, just filter on `[python] or [python-2.7] or [python-3.x]` and you're done)
- Another argument is that many people have the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) gold badge, and are able to singlehandedly close as duplicate if needed, whereas fewer people have [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) or [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) gold badge, and if a user edits to add the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), he/she's not allowed to hammer the post afterwards (that could lead to abuse)

I personally don't see any question that could be only python 2.7 related, and not python related. I've never seen a revert by OP or other users when the generic tag was added. And I add it on each python question that doesn't have it, good or bad.