# Should we centralize [decentralized] and [distributed]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

[decentralized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decentralized) currently has 6 questions and no wiki. It looks like it's a duplicate of [distributed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/distributed).

Should we make [decentralized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decentralized) a synonym of [distributed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/distributed)?

Comment: Just do it? You've got enough powers to remove [tag:decentralized] completely.

Comment: [tag:centralized] might also need the same treatment

Comment: Probably yes, are there more question you can't handle yourself? 67 still isn't massive (takes you 5 minutes or so).

Comment: [tag:decentralized] is burninated, I don't have time to clean up [tag:centralized], and I cannot create a tag synonym for [tag:decentralized] from [tag:distributed] myself.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Burninating without a post should be discouraged for [the reasons here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288784/1394393). Also, I would consider 5 minutes for 67 questions to likely be robo-reviewing.

Comment: Those 6 questions in [tag:decentralized] took more than 5 minutes, because for some questions, the tag should be changed, and for others, it should be removed.